# Eigendecomposition of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $PL = L^TP$ where $P$ is a diagonal matrix.

Also, suppose $L$ has the property that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ is the corresponding right eigenvector, then the corresponding left eigenvector is $u = Pv$.

I want to use these facts to show the eigendecomposition of $L$ is

$$L = V\Lambda V^TP$$

I was told to relate the eigenvector of $L' = P^{1/2}LP^{-1/2}$ to $L$, but I'm not quite sure how to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the eigendecomposition of $L$ is $L = V\Lambda V^TP$"? This isn't the conventional way to write an eigendecomposition; is the $P$ supposed to appear in that equation? Is $\Lambda$ supposed to be diagonal? Is $V$ supposed to be orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

You know from your previous post that $L = P^{-1}Q$, where the $Q = PL$ is symmetric. Note therefore that the matrix
$$
L' = P^{1/2}[L]P^{-1/2} = P^{1/2}[P^{-1}Q]P^{-1/2} = P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2}
$$
is symmetric. The spectral theorem tells us that there exists an orthogonal matrix $V$ for which
$$
L' = V \Lambda V^T.
$$
That is, we have
$$
P^{1/2}LP^{-1/2} = V \Lambda V^T \implies\\
L = (P^{-1/2} V) \Lambda (V^T P^{1/2}) \implies\\
L = (P^{-1/2}V) \Lambda (P^{-1/2}V)^{-1},
$$
which is indeed an eigendecomposition of $L$.

Comment: I don't actually have any information about $\Lambda$ or $V$, but I'm guessing $V$ should be orthogonal. However, I do know that all entries in $P$ are positive. Does this help? I tried to simplify the final line you've written, but I can't quite get it in the correct form. I used $(P^{-1/2}V)^{-1} = V^{-1}P^{1/2} = V^{T}P^{1/2}$ so $L = P^{-1/2}V\Lambda V^{T}P^{1/2}$

Comment: @gks I had a typo in the second to last line, do things make more sense now?

Comment: But shouldn't it be of the form $V\Lambda V^TP?$ Or can I somehow simplify the last line to that form? If I can somehow simplify it to that form, I'm struggling to do so.

Comment: I'm also a little confused because we never used the eigenvalue assumption in my second paragraph. Is that not needed?

Comment: @gks As I imply in my comment on your question, I suspect that there is some kind of typo so I did the best I could at doing something reasonable that matches your description. I indeed did not use the information from the second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry - I just realized $V$ is a matrix of right eigenvectors, normalized so $P^{1/2}V$ is orthogonal. This means that $P^{1/2}V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $L'$, but I still can't quite finish from here.